# ERROR: You attempted to use a firebase module that's not installed on your Android project by calling firebase.app() WITH EXPO

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-fcm

I'm using `react-native-firebase/messaging` and I'm working with the expo.
I tried using `messaging().getToken();` but this error occurred
`

```
Error: You attempted to use a firebase module that's not installed on 
     your Android project by calling firebase.app().

Ensure you have:

1) imported the 
'io.invertase.firebase.app.ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage' module in your 
'MainApplication.java' file.

2) Added the 'new ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage()' line inside of the RN 
'getPackages()' method list.

 See http://invertase.link/android for full setup instructions.`
```

I followed the expo docs steps to use the firebase sdk but I keep getting this error. This is the configuration in `app.json`:

```
"ios": {
  "supportsTablet": true,
  "bundleIdentifier": "com.siriusnet.tiwsal",
  "buildNumber": "1.0.0"
},
"android": {
  "package": "com.siriusnet.tiwsal",
  "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json",
  "versionCode": 1,
  "adaptiveIcon": {
    "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
    "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
  }
},
```

Comment: Did you installed and initialized the firebase properly. Because it seems like you are missing the Firebase module in your project.

Comment: Yes, `expo install @react-native-firebase/app`  and `expo install @react-native-firebase/messaging` and I added the google service file in the app.json

Comment: So, it is just messaging or other Firebase features are also not working.

Comment: Hey there! Did you find a way out of this issue? Got the same problem here!